# How to get the sum of multiple numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
k = 1
M = input("Enter an integer: ")
for M in range(k,M):
    s = 1/float(M)
    print sum(s)
```

How do I get the sum of `s`? I keep getting an error message:

```
File "C:/Python27/summation.py", line 7, in <module>
  print sum(s)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: *sum* of what? Of a single element?

Comment: Please provide the whole error message that you get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is not a list it is a float.  Try this instead:

```
k = 1
M = input("Enter an integer:")
print sum(1/float(s) for s in range(k, M))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s=[]
k = 1
M = input("Enter an integer: ")
for M in range(k,M):
    s.append(1/float(M))
print(s)
print(sum(s))
```

Output(M=10):

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.125, 0.1111111111111111]
2.8289682539682537
```

Answer (score 0):

In this source code, value M is override twice. So if change the M in the for loop, you can get the sum of s. 
The fixed coed is below.

```
k = 1
M = input("Enter an integer: ")
S = []
for V in range(k,M): S.append(V)
print sum(s)
```

Also, If you want to get a sum of list, you must make a value list and append the value(V) in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code:

```
result = 0
k = 1
M = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
for M in range(k, M):
    result += (1 / float(M))
print(result)
```

How it works? It will ask for an input, and do the operation. The result of each cycle of the loop will be added to a variable called result.

Simple, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to count the sum of 1/1.0 + ... + 1/yourInput.

You can use the method below.

```
def getSum(yourInput):
    scoreLst = [1/float(e) for e in range(1, yourInput)]
    return sum(scoreLst)
```

e.g:getSum(10), you will get the output:2.828...